# Beamer second footcite changes style

Tags: beamer

My problem is that when second item gets visible, the citation style slightly changes (disappears journal, colored fonts), therefore the position of first item changes:

```
\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{article1,
   Day = {30},
   Edition = {2},
   Month = {jun},
   Publisher = {Artech House Publishers},
   author = {Taflove, Allen and Hagness, Susan C.},
   title = {Computational Electrodynamics: The Finite-Difference Time-Domain Method},
   year = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Title~\footfullcite{article1}}
   \begin{itemize}[<+->]
       \item a
       \item b
       \item c
       \end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to keep the citation style constant (including the journal name)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @cfr: I have changed the code.

Comment: It seems that if I use footfullcite instead of footcite there is no problem.

Comment: The MWE does not reproduce the described problem.